# How to delete subsite that hasn't any permissions in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: permissions

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site. And there is a subsite. While assigning unique permissions, I accidentally deleted all permissions, and now I cannot handle this subsite, because I haven't rights to control it. So I cannot delete it. If you faced such problem, please be kind to hint me.

Comment: Uhm...about what kind of system you're talking about?

Comment: @akluth, Sorry, it is SP2010, I thought that this is sharepoint.stackexchange.com :)